# SALT Software transcription

Tags: aave

When using the SALT software, how does one transcribe non-standard verb tenses used in AAVE. For example, "We  is going to the store."

Comment: If you're not transcribing it phonetically, you don't have the tools to transcribe AAVE or any other nonstandard lect. This is why sociolinguists use tape recorders, Praat, and R.